# Given $f'''(x)=e^x $with $f''(0)=6$, $f'(0)=10$

Tags: calculus

I can't begin to think on how to solve this problems:

Given $f'''(x)=e^x$ with $f''(0)=6$, $f'(0)=10$,

then $f(x)= \underline{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ }              + C$

Note that your answer should not contain a general constant.

I've been staring at this problem for awhile and its nothing similar to the other problems I've done. Whats the best way to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something to get you going.

If $f'''(x) = e^x$, then you know that $f''(x) = e^x+A$ for some constant $A$.

But you are given the information that $f''(0)=6$, which in the expression for $f''(x)$ means that

$$e^0+A = 6,$$

or

$$1+A = 6,$$

or

$$A=5.$$

In total, $f''(x) = e^x+5$.

Can you do the same thing for $f'(x)$?

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{d(f''(x))}{dx}=e^x$$

$$\int d(f''(x))=\int e^x\ dx\iff f''(x)=e^x+K$$

$f''(0)=e^0+K$  but $f''(0)=6$

Carry on with repeated integration.

Answer (score 2):

You should know that the general anti-derivative of $f'''\colon x\mapsto e^x$ is $f''\colon x\mapsto e^x + c_1$. The general antiderivative of that is $f'\colon x\mapsto e^x + c_1x+c_2$ and the anti-derivative of that is $f\colon x\mapsto \frac12c_1x^2+c_2x+c_3$. You can determine $c_1, c_2$ from $f''(0)$ and $f'(0)$ and the remaining constant $c_3$ is (under the name $C$) part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{d^3e^x}{dx^3}=e^x \implies \frac{d^2e^x}{dx^2}=e^x +C_1 \implies \frac{de^x}{dx}=e^x+C_1x+C_2$$